# How to change the url of checkout in toplink

Tags: magento-1.9, toplinks

I need to change the url that the checkout link in top links is pointing to. At the moment it point to /checkout but i need it to point to /checkout/onepage.

normally the redirect it automatic but i have an extension with conflict with this auto redirect so i just want to change the top link so there is no re direct.

I found this

```
    <reference name="top.links">
        <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
            <action method="addCartLink"></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

but i dont know how to change the url on the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rewrite the block `Mage_Checkout_Block_Links`. [Here is a tutorial on how to do that](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/),
and you need to change the method `addCheckoutLink` and make it look like this:

```
public function addCheckoutLink()
{
    if (!$this->helper('checkout')->canOnepageCheckout()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
    if ($parentBlock && Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
        $text = $this->__('Checkout');
        $parentBlock->addLink(
            $text, 'checkout/onepage', $text,
            true, array('_secure' => true), 60, null,
            'class="top-link-checkout"'
        );
    }
    return $this;
}
```

the only difference is that this line `$text, 'checkout', $text,` becomes `$text, 'checkout/onepage', $text,`

Answer (score 3):

Path:-app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Links.php

copy the file to your Local folder otherwise overwrite the block file. and change the url in `addLink()` function.

here I change the url based on theme name.

```
public function addCheckoutLink()
{

    if (!$this->helper('onestepcheckout')->isRewriteCheckoutLinksEnabled()){
        return parent::addCheckoutLink();
    }

    if (!$this->helper('checkout')->canOnepageCheckout()) {
        return $this;
    }
    if ($parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock()) {
        $text = $this->__('Checkout');
         $theme_name =  Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme('frontend');
         if($theme_name=='Your-Theme-Name'){
             $parentBlock->addLink($text, 'checkout/onepage', $text, true, array('_secure'=>true), 60, null, 'class="top-link-onestepcheckout"');
         }else {
            $parentBlock->addLink($text, 'onestepcheckout', $text, true, array('_secure'=>true), 60, null, 'class="top-link-onestepcheckout"');
         }
    }
    return $this;
}
```